# Adding a specific layer to ArcGIS Online WebMap/API Application via GeoServer WFS

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, wfs

I am hosting a few different workspaces and layers on my GeoServer WFS, and would like to add a specific layer from that collection to my ArcGIS Online WebMap and also a simple web mapping application I am building that takes a link to a service and adds the layer to my map.

I have tried a few variations of the following request, trying to pull a layer called "countries" from a workspace called "CountryBoundaries":

```
https://server:port/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=CountryBoundaries:countries
```

When trying this on the ArcGIS Online web map builder I get a "Service Error - Unable to Load, Status:504" message, when trying in my API application to construct a new WFSLayer object, it adds another layer from a separate workspace within my GeoServer that I didn't specify.

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: @IanTurton edited the original post to include that

Comment: OK, does the URL work in your browser? what does the GeoServer log file say the problem is? what headers does ArcGIS send? is it a CORS issue?

Comment: The URL does work in the browser, it returns an XML of all of the features within the layer, and it doesn't look like there are any errors on the GeoServer side.  I don't believe it is a CORS issue, because when adding this link in our application built via the API, it DOES add a layer, just a different one from our WFS.  It looks like it is adding the very first layer available via WFS in the GetCapabilities XML, as opposed to this specific one. Is there a way to create a simple WFS endpoint to a workspace/layer as opposed to having to structure a query like this?

Comment: You could try the experimental OGC Features API but it's still in development. If it loads a layer but not the right one then it sounds like the wrong type name is being requested, you need to check the log file

Comment: You have a tag for the ArcGIS JavaScript API but have not presented any code.